# Mac Xamarin Studio - how to get context-based help on syntax

Tags: osx-yosemite, xamarin-studio

In Visual Studio, you can hover over an element the press F1 to get more information on syntax and usage. How do I get this same help in Xamarin Studio on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Studio, you can just mouse over or hover the curser over the text you wish to see more information on.